# Error installing Sylius: "PHP Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required autoload.php"

Tags: php, symfony, xampp, pear, sylius

I tried to install Sylius (Symfony) with the command `"(php bin/console sylius:install")`, but it gives the below error:

> PHP Warning:  require(C:\xampp\htdocs\acme\bin/../vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\acme\bin\console on line 16
>
> Warning: require(C:\xampp\htdocs\acme\bin/../vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\acme\bin\console on line 16
>
> PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required 'C:\xampp\htdocs\acme\bin/../vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\acme\bin\console on line 16
>
> Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'C:\xampp\htdocs\acme\bin/../vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\acme\bin\console on line 16

Comment: did composer create-project command was finished properly? The easiest way is to try to create project in new directory

Answer (score 0):

Please check your installed PHP version. Most likely it's 5.6. Since Sylius requires > PHP7.1 composer resolves Sylius to to the older version (something pre-beta) based on Symfony 2. Symfony3 moved `console` from `app/` to `bin/` folder.

**Solution**
Please install PHP 7.1 locally, remove vendor folder and run `composer install` again