# Sylius on OSX bin/console missing

Tags: php, macos, sylius, bin, missing-features

Just execute composer 
create-project sylius/sylius-standard acme
on OSX.

But when executing

```
    php bin/console sylius:install
```

or

```
    bin/console sylius:install
```

The error 'Could not open input file: bin/console' appears.
No wonder, bin/console does not exist.
How does that happen?
Do I have to download it from github?
Any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46388614/error-installing-sylius-php-fatal-error-require-failed-opening-required-au

Comment: you need to install php7.1 and then execute `composer create-project sylius/sylius-standard` again in other directory

Answer (score 0):

Does `php app/console sylius:install` work? If so you might have an older version. That happened to me the other day. I had to pull the git repo to get the latest.

Then I learned I needed to update php. I was running 5.6. Now I have 7.1